# Angular6 application adding jquery by default

Tags: jquery, angular

I am simply trying to add owl-carousel in angular application but without npm as nothing is dynamic there. But the same was not working. So when inspecting in Chrome. I am getting the following:

`<script async="" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

It is being added just before body gets an end. While going through index.html and angular.json. I find no such mention.

Don't know from where it is getting but this is added in the end before owl carousel is getting called.

Either I want it to be removed so that I may add it manually in Index.html or lifted it up before owl is called.

Here is my angular.json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "jsm": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {},
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/jsm",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/assets/css/new-age.css", "src/assets/css/imp.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js", "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "jsm:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "jsm:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "jsm:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "jsm-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "jsm:serve"
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "jsm"
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your webpack config or knowing what version of anything you're using, or seeing any code whatsoever, this will be a difficult one to answer. There is nothing in the new version of Owl Carousel that automatically adds jquery.

Comment: owl carousel in not adding any jquery but Angular6 does

Comment: I added my angular.json file

Comment: How are you adding the owl script to your application?

Comment: I am simply adding it in index.html

Comment: My carousel is static, so thought to use it with simplicity